# log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [Console] of type [log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender]. Reported error

Tags: .net-core, log4net

Hello friend I have the following problem when trying to use log4net in net core in my console application.

My code is this:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Teltonika.Codec;

namespace UdpListener
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
        static void Main()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            IPAddress ip;
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ipAddress"], out ip))
            {
                Log.Error("Ip is not valid.");
                throw new ArgumentException("Ip is not valid.");
            }

            int port;
            if (!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"], out port))
            {
                Log.Error("Port is not valid.");
                throw new ArgumentException("Port is not valid.");
            }

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(ip, port)))
                    {
                        Log.Info("Listening...");

                        while (true)
                        {
                            //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
                                var receivedResults = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();

                            byte[] data = receivedResults.Buffer;


                            //tramaService.InsertTrama(new Entity.GpsPuntos()
                            //{
                            //    Fecha = DateTime.Now,
                            //    Trama = String.Join("", data.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray())
                            //});


                            Log.Info(string.Format("Received connection from: {0}", receivedResults.RemoteEndPoint));
                            Log.Info(string.Format("{0} - received [{1}]", DateTime.Now, String.Join("", data.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray())));

                            var reader = new ReverseBinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));

                            // Decode data
                            var avlData = new DataDecoder(reader).DecodeUdpData();

                            // Create response
                            var bytes = new List<byte>();

                            const short packetLength = 2 /* Id */+ 1 /* Type */ + 1 /* Avl packet id */+ 1 /* num of accepted elems */;
                            bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(BytesSwapper.Swap(packetLength)));
                            bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(BytesSwapper.Swap(avlData.PacketId)));
                            bytes.Add(avlData.PacketType);
                            bytes.Add(avlData.AvlPacketId);
                            bytes.Add((byte)avlData.AvlData.DataCount);

                            var response = bytes.ToArray();

                            Log.Info(string.Format("{0} - response [{1}]", DateTime.Now, String.Join("", bytes.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray())));

                            await udpClient.SendAsync(response, response.Length, receivedResults.RemoteEndPoint);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }

            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

this my mistake

log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [Console] of type [log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender]. Reported error follows.
System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 850. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Int32 codepage)
at log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender.ActivateOptions()
at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
log4net:ERROR Appender named [Console] not found.

My archive configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="ipAddress" value="172.17.160.1"/>
        <add key="port" value="3316"/>
        <!--<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>-->
    </appSettings>

    <log4net>
        <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender" Target="Console.Error">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%logger - %message%newline"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
        
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="log.txt"/>
            <appendToFile value="true"/>
            <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
            <maximumFileSize value="500KB"/>
            <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%d %-5p %c %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I want it to show me in the console application that it is working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had this same error myself today after upgrading from .NET Framework to .NET 5. I managed to get around it by adding the following line at the start of my program:

```cs
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(
    System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Comment: Worked for me on .NET Core 3.1, btw. -- Thank you. 

Answer (score 7):

For me this was solved by using the `ManagedColoredConsoleAppender` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **ManagedColoredConsoleAppender** is a better solution if you want to run the application also on other OS's besides Windows.

The **ColoredConsoleAppender** depends on the **kernel32.dll**, which **ManagedColoredConsoleAppender** does not.

See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-658.